# How to echo the contents of one page in another page?

Tags: php

I am doing client customizations and i have multiple files.  If for example i want to show the code of page 1.php on page home.php, how can i do it by echoing it or something.  Please help me.  Thanks!

Comment: Related:  http://serverfault.com/q/62410/70463

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) files in a `PHP` script by adding this your `home.php` file:

```
if ($example){
include("page 1");
}
else {
include("Error.php");
}
```

Or another way to do is [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$content = file_get_contents($file_path);
echo $content;
```

Comment: @nikic: what is this? I did not understand

Comment: does this have any security concerns Shakti or is safe t ouse?

Comment: @KPO: You can use `include`, `include_once`,`file_get_contents` freely.

Comment: If you're just going to echo the result of `file_get_contents()` without doing any processing, you might as well use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile).

Answer (score 4):

If including the scripts won't work, then you will need the workaround over the local webserver to merge just the contents (still need to cut out the content/body part):

```
print(file_get_contents("http://$_SERVER[SERVER_NAME]/page1.php"));
```

But a saner solution is most always just using an iframe and have the page inclusion handled by the browser:

```
<iframe src="page1.php" width="500" height="400" ></iframe>
```

Or more newfangled with some jQuery:

```
<div id="page1"></div>
<script>$("#page1").load("page1.php body");</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `include()` or `require()`. Make sure you add one of these statements at the top of your code.

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is some info from the php manual.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to echo plain text use

```
echo file_get_contents('1.php');
```