# Get file name index.php in an inluded file

Tags: php, server, echo

I want to get file name from URL in an included page for example in meta.php

I use `basename(__FILE__)` but I get 'meta.php'

how I can echo **index.php** in an included page??

```
<meta name="description" content="<?php 
if(isset($FILEDATA_LANG['page_'.basename(__FILE__).'_keywords'])){ echo 
$FILEDATA_LANG['page_'.basename(__FILE__).'_keywords']; }?>">
```

Comment: Is this question answer helpful, for your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5755241/how-to-echo-the-contents-of-one-page-in-another-page

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked earlier and you could've found your answer within seconds of searching, however, here's a proper response:

Set a variable in your `index.php` or a definition, such as:

`define("THIS_PAGE", __FILE__);` or `$thisPage = __FILE__;`

Then in your file you're including (after this variable), simply use:
`<?php echo $thisPage; ?>` or `<?php echo THIS_PAGE; ?>`.
(Keep in mind to check if the variable is set `(isset($thisPage))` or `(defined("THIS_PAGE"))`.

Reference: [Get filename of file which ran PHP include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393145/get-filename-of-file-which-ran-php-include)

Answer (score -1):

I'm trying by adding
`.basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).`
I Hope it would work when i publish this page